# How [FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:nil] works?

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, fbdialogs

Does anyone make [FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:nil] works properly ?
It's always returning me NO. What should I put in params ?

```
    if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:nil]) {
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.fr"];
    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:url
                                  handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                      if(error) {
                                          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                      } else {
                                          NSLog(@"Success!");
                                      }
                                  }];
} else {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        SLComposeViewController *fbComposer = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [fbComposer setInitialText:@"Google rocks !"];
        [self presentViewController:fbComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Informations" message:@"You have to be registered into the settings of your phone in order to share" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the HelloFacebookSample from the SDK (and my own experience!):

```
FBShareDialogParams *p = [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init];
p.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developers.facebook.com/ios"];
BOOL canShareFB = [FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:p];
```

*canShareFB* will return **YES** if the Facebook app **is installed** in the system; returns **NO** if **no Facebook** app is found.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is it always returns **NO**.
I think this the issue.

Comment: In my case it's always return **NO**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to pass a non-nil instance of FBShareDialogParams to the canPresentShareDialogWithParams method.  The SDK expects to receive a valid instance of FBShareDialogParmas so the SDK can make sure that the version of the Facebook app on the device can actually open the content that's going to be shared.

For example, if FB adds support for sharing video via Share Dialog in a future version of the Facebook app on iOS, the canPresentShareDialogWithParams would return NO if an older version of the Facebook app is present on the device.

I can understand how the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/ios/share-dialog/ might be confusing here (apologies!).  We'll update them to reflect this.

Thanks for the feedback; hope that helps!